# Plant identification: Elaeagnus × Ebbingei "Gilt Edge"?

Tags: identification, shrubs, landscaping

I'm on a learning mission to figure out what are growing around my house. This one has green leaves with yellow rings. Is it [Elaeagnus × Ebbingei "Gilt Edge" / oleaster / Ebbing's silverberry](https://jcraulstonarboretum.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/elaeagnus-c397ebbingei-gilt-edge.jpg)?

[image: Elaeagnus × ebbingei]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *Elaeagnus*, the leaves are too small and not leathery enough and the growth habit is wrong. It's most likely a *Euonymus* variety - judging by its growth habit, it's more likely to be *Euonymus fortunei*, perhaps the variety 'Emerald and Gold' (sometimes called green and gold) rather than *E.japonica*, which tends to grow much taller without spreading out so much.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.gardenia.net/plant/euonymus-fortunei-emerald-n-gold-wintercreeper? The long stems and strings of leaves do not look like much I can find on the web.

Comment: Possibly Euonymus "Emerald 'n' Gold"? If we want to keep the nice variegated leaves you might want to cut out the reverted stems (ie the ones with green leaves), though it's not compulsory.

Comment: You just need to tidy it up, its been left to its own devices too long - it often puts out long sprawly growth sideways,, often along the ground, and you get all green stems as well, as you can see in your photo. I usually prune out most or all green growth, cut off trailing stems and reshape the whole plant by clipping it over in spring, around now.

Comment: Ah, I see. Tons to learn with new home ownership. Thank you both!